# How to autowire a property which has no beans defined, using @Autowired DI on constructor?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I have an EquityOrder class consisting of List of Equity and a String as its properties. A method "placeOrder" is also defined. I have autowired my constructor and beans for Equity have been defined in my XML file.

```
@Autowired
public EquityOrder(String name, List<Equity> equity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.equity = equity;
}

public void placeOrder() {

    for (Equity eq : equity)
        System.out.println("Placing order for " + eq.getSecurityName()
                + "with quantity " + eq.getQuantity());
}
```

In the xml I have below scenario, which is error free.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean name="testEquity" class="com.sapient.Spring.Equity.Equity">

    <property name="symbol" value="MSFT"></property>
    <property name="securityName" value="Microsoft"></property>
    <property name="type" value="IT"></property>
    <property name="quantity" value="100"></property>

</bean>

<bean name="testOtherEquity" class="com.sapient.Spring.Equity.Equity">

    <constructor-arg value="GOOG">
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="Google"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="IT"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="100"></constructor-arg>

</bean>

<bean name="testEquityOrder" class="com.sapient.Spring.Equity.EquityOrder">
</bean>
```

Issue - when in the constructor I have no String, then the project runs fine. But if the constructor has the String in it, it throws exception as -

```
Error creating bean with name 'testEquityOrder' defined in class path resource 
[SpringConfig.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with 
index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found
for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this
dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of 
type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

which means the container is looking for String bean but it can not be there. How to solve this issue. One way is to use annotation on setter. But how to do it using the `@Autowire` annotation on Constructor? Thanks

Comment: How would spring understand what are you attempting to autowire? And what is the name? Or is it the name of the bean?

Comment: Spring is that much intelligent, I assume. We do not have to do anything extra, other than <context:annotation-config />.

Comment: I suggest you take another pass at understanding DI and the IoC pattern. This is not a correct usage of it. Data-objects are not dependencies and when it looks like your object is both situational and dependent on dynamic input then you want direct control of the creation and building of the object, not inverted control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide value for the name attribute using the `<constructor-arg>` element as follows:

```
<bean name="testEquityOrder" class="com.sapient.Spring.Equity.EquityOrder">
    <constructor-arg value="dummyValue" />
</bean>
```

The other constructor argument anyway gets autowired as it's a bean already defined.

P.S. Also, I must say that EquityOrder appears to be a data object and unless it is some configuration data, it shouldn't be injected/autowired like this if it depends on the user input.